# How to efficiently convert a list into probability distribution?

Tags: python, arrays, performance

I am trying to convert a list into probability distribution.

```
x = [2, 4]
```

I want it the following array in that order.

```
probability_array = [1-(2+4)/10, 2/10, 4/10]
```

So I did the following...

```
y = 1 - (2 + 4)/10
new_x = [2/10, 4/10]
probability_array = [y] + new_x
```

The problem is I'm working with 10,000 data sets like `x`. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Why are you dividing by 10, and not any other number? It would probably make more sense to divide all of that by `sum(x)`.

Comment: 10,000 isn't that many. Are you sure this needs to be optimized? See [When to optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: Outside @martineau's very sensible comment and guessing that the values are in [0-10] you can either precompute or memoize/cache (all or a subset).

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time to look at my question. @Martineau I'm trying to optimise expected goal in football (soccer) match by measuring the sum of squared difference against the individual match timeslot. The 10 above can be taken as the timeslot per match. This is done by simply adjusting the xG with arbitrary multiplier. Then try to optimise the arbitrary multiplier that gives the best result (lowest average SSE per timeslot for large dataset, 10,000).

Comment: Abs: I see, then perhaps if you edited your question and changed the example so it was in terms of what you wanted in terms of abstract / algebraic quantities (i.e. input variables and how they relate to the desired result) instead of one case and a bunch of literal values—and mention how often you'll be applying that operation as well as the size of the dataset. Might also want to indicate whether using something like `numpy` or other third-party libraries was an option (as opposed to being restricted to pure Python and the ones included with it).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this easily with numpy. Here is an example of **correctness**

```
x=[[1, 2], [3,4]]
x=np.array(x)
sum1 = np.sum(x, axis=1).reshape(2,1)
prob = x/sum1
```

I think it would be pretty fast even if size of x>10000. Let's take **100 features** for **10000 examples**

```
x=np.random.randint(1, 100, size=1000000)
print(x.shape)
start=time.time()
x=x.reshape(-1, 10000)
sum1=np.sum(x, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
prob=x/sum1
stop=time.time()
print(stop-start)
```

This takes around **0.021** sec on my MBP.